# Insert/replace string in existing text form field in Word (VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-word, form-fields

So I'm trying to create a conditional dropdown in Word. I've used a Legacy Drop-Down Form Field with multiple options.

What I want to happen is when one of the options is selected from the dropdown (and then I guess you have to Tab to enter it...), the Legacy Text Form Field below, that has a simple default text, should populate with a new string from the case statement.

Things that I've already done/got working:

- the drop down is working, and on exit it runs a macro
- case statement is written out
- the result of the case statement is in a variable (string type), let's call it StringVar
- can pull the text form field's text (default text) with ActiveDocument.FormFields("TextBox").Result

What I figure out, however, is how to replace the default text in the already existing Text Form Field with the case statement's string variable text.

I've tried 
ActiveDocument.FormFields("TextBox").Result = StringVar

but it doesn't change anything inside the text form field. The default text is still there.

Answer (score 1):

So I can answer my own question after pondering and being hit with an "oh, duh" moment.

I had unprotected the document (ActiveDocument.Unprotect Password:="") in order to do this:

ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter Text:=("This is my text")

because I was wondering if I was grabbing the right string.

Turns out,

ActiveDocument.FormFields("TextBox").Result = StringVar

DOES work. BUT the file has to be **protected** (filling in forms) for it to replace the string in the text form field. Otherwise, nothing shows up even though the result had indeed been updated. Fancy that.